# Is there a way to access public members from private function in a CoffeeScript class

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

How do you convert this CoffeeScript function into a class such that public members can be access by private members ?

```
MyClass= -> 
  prVar = 'private'
  prMethod1 = -> 
    console.log 'prMethod'
    self.pubMethod2() 

  public_members =
    pubVar : 'public'
    pubMethod1: -> 
      console.log 'pubMethod1'
      prMethod1() 
    pubMethod2: -> 
      console.log 'pubMethod2'
return public_members 

my = new MyClass()
my.pubMethod1()
```

class MyClass
??

Comment: In a number of languages, including JavaScript and CoffeeScript, public and private class members are a convention rather than an enforced feature. In CoffeeScript you signify a private member by prefixing its name with an _ underscore. Hope this helps.

Comment: Bijou I agree with you. Public and private are based on convention. I think making a base model klass where i can extend and include members might be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code help you :

```
@MyClass= -> 
  prVar = 'private'
  prMethod1 = -> 
    console.log 'prMethod'
    public_members.pubMethod2() 

  public_members =
    pubVar : 'public'
    pubMethod1: -> 
      console.log 'pubMethod1'
      prMethod1() 
    pubMethod2: ->  
      console.log 'pubMethod2'
  return public_members
```

Comment: I understand how to use it with functions but is there a  way to to do this using coffeescript keyword class?